# Sample size confidence level

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Let me start out by saying I took statistics in college but although I passed I have no ability to answer this question. If I'm missing something please be kind and let me know what more I need to add to the question. I've looked at other similar questions but I don't know how to apply them to my question.

Here's the question:

I had Bob analyze 2000 records with 3 equally distributed options: red, yellow, green. I ask the tester to enter red=1, yellow=2, green =3. I want to analyze how competent Bob  was. I want to know what the formula to find the smallest sample size that I can analyze to ensure that Bob was correct at least X% of the time, I'm calling X a confidence score.

P= population size
S= sample size
X = confidence score percentage

What is the formula for S = ?

Is there something that I'm missing that is limiting you from answering the question?

I have a real problem that this example is depicting but I wanted to simplify it to this example. Please help, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: You want a power analysis.

Comment: Please elaborate